# Remove margins of embedded web page

Tags: html, css, object, embed, margin

I am trying to embed my Bandcamp page onto my website but there are some undesired side margins:

http://bandcamp.nummermusic.com/

The original embedded page being:

https://nummer.bandcamp.com/

I tried a few things but so far such as iframe instead of object, added some css properties like margin:

`object{float:left;margin:0em 0em 0em 0em;display:block;}`

But everything I tried led to the same results.

Any idea?

Comment: show us what you have tried!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `margin:0px` to your body CSS.

It would be better to use an iframe here rather than an object, unless you have a specific reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

body { margin : 0 }

seem to fix it for me.

Doesn't it for you ? Am i missing something ? What browser are you using ?

Comment: No, your not missing anything. OP shows he has tried adding his `margin` CSS to the object, not the body.